# How fo i retrieve option label instead of option value

Tags: php, dropdown

I want to echo the Approve / reject instead of the 
value that is stored in the database. How do i achieve this in PHP?

```
<select name="supAprrove" id="supAprrove">
    <option value="1" >Approve</option>
    <option value="2">Reject</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Why not just use Approve and Reject for both the label and the value?

Comment: the database is already using int for that field. i need the label in a meesage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with a ternary statement:

```
echo $_POST['supAprrove'] == 1 ? 'Approve' : 'Reject';
```

The statement is a shorthand if/else. The condition before the `?` is evaluated. If it evaluates to `true`, then you get the result of the statement after the `?`, otherwise you get the result of the statement after the `:`.